DaisyUI - tailwindcss, how can I change the background color of HTML using react?
I added these three App, HTML, and the tailwind config file to make sure it is #020158
<body style="background-color: #020158">

<div className="bg-background w-full h-full">

import daisyui from "daisyui";

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        background: "#020158",
        foreground: "#020158",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
  daisyui: {
    themes: {
      extend: {
        colors: {
          background: "#020158",
          foreground: "#020158",
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

The color is set to #020158 after the loading. But, when I refresh it I still see the different color on the background. I am trying to override that and it seems to be impossible except removing the daisyUI component.
I've been trying to override the setting on config file and did not work too. How can I make sure the HTML plate is set to #020158 not the DaisyUI background Color?

For me adding in the html did the trick. what color do you see on refresh?
